# Use WatchKit button to record from iPhone

Tags: ios, objective-c, watchkit

I have a function in iOS code that records the audio from iPhone.

Now, I want to start recording once I pressed a button from WatchKit app. The recording will be done on the phone, not apple watch.

I'm using the following code on WatchKit to send signal to iPhone to start recording.

```
[self.session sendMessage:@{"command": "start"} replyHandler:nil errorHandler:nil]
```

And I have the following handler on iOS code.

```
- (void) session:(WCSession *)session didReceiveMessage:(NSDictionary<NSString *,id> *)message replyHandler:(void (^)(NSDictionary<NSString *,id> * _Nonnull))replyHandler
```

Once I receive the command from WatchKit, I called my recording function on iOS code.

It runs successfully. However, the output file is empty, and the data length is 0.

Is it possible to do so? Or will I need to record from WatchKit separately?

Thanks.

Comment: Perhaps it's a permissions problem where your app can only record audio in the foreground. watchOS `sendMessage` doesn't bring the iOS app to the foreground. Is your iOS app recording the audio in the foreground or in the background?

Comment: @PetahChristian, my app has background recording now. I can see the red double status bar when I pressed on WatchKit. However, the data length of my file is still zero. Thanks...

Comment: @PetahChristian, i was able to solve it. It's because I'm calling the function from background thread. Using GCD to call from main thread solved it. Thanks.

Comment: Great! You should post your solution as an answer to help anyone else looking for help with remotely recording audio.

Answer (score 0):

The `WCSession` functionality is solely a message-passing system. Once your iPhone application has received the message, the iPhone application is able to execute any code that it can normally execute. As you indicate that you are successfully receiving the message, the problem is not with the `WCSession` code. Note, however, that all messages received by your app are delivered to the session delegate serially on a background thread. Comments above indicate that in your specific use case, recognising this was key to ensuring that the process you planned to initiate was on the main thread.

In short, to answer the specific question raised in your question, yes, you can initiate recording on an iPhone with a button on the Apple Watch—providing the iPhone app is running at the time the button is tapped, as that is a prerequisite for the `WCSession` protocol.

Given that, one obvious addition if you don't already have this would be to check for `if (session.reachable)` in your WatchKit App Extension and to disable the button if it is not, as well as registering for notifications for when the session reachability changes so that you can re-enable the button.